# java system.getenv(HOME) returns tomcat6 directory

Tags: java, variables, ubuntu, environment

Hi as the subject reads

```
System.getenv("HOME")
```

in my action class (struts2) and deploy that as a war in

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/
```

When i run my class, getenv HOME returns

```
/var/lib/tomcat6
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on?  I even tested it out on a standalone java class.Returns the proper value of home. Tried it on shell also `echo $HOME` and it gives a proper output.

Running on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Is your runscript setting it?

Comment: @Mark Didnt quite follow you.. runscript as in ..

Comment: Are you running tomcat as a service, or starting it using a shell script?

Comment: How is tomcat launched?  Using the init.d script?  By hand?  What user is used to run it?  What is that user's $HOME?  What value do you expect for $HOME?

Comment: Tomcat is started by doing "sudo service tomcat6 start" thats it. 
You think sudo is giving problems?
$HOME should give "/home/infinishare" instead of which its giving me 
/var/lib/tomcat6

Comment: i THINK ive got what the problem is.. My project got deployed with permissions for "tomcat6 tomcat6" so when i getenv HOME, it gives me tomcat home. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i THINK ive got what the problem is.. My project got deployed with permissions for "tomcat6 tomcat6" so when i getenv HOME, it gives me tomcat home. Am I right?

No.

The problem is that your tomcat6 service is configured to run as the "tomcat" user.  (There is typically a variable in the init.d/tomcatd script that does this ...)  THIS IS DONE FOR SECURITY REASONS.  Don't change it unless you've done a proper risk assessment.

What you really need to do is change your web application so that it doesn't expect $HOME to be >>your<< home directory.  Instead, create a webapp specific properties file that gives the location of this external (to tomcat) directory.  Or better still (and best practice!) change your application so that it doesn't need to refer to an external directory at all.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I guess i'll have to talk to my seniors since the external folder was being used for a specific feature of the webapp. Thanks for the nice explanation!